# Mockito test case not covering internal function call

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

HI i am trying to develop test cases with JUNIT + MOCKITO and facing an issue due to this ..

This is the method which i am trying to test

```
    public Response create(Request request)
      throws SQLException, InvalidSecretKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, GeneralSecurityException,
      InvalidParametersException, InvalidAuthKeyException, ConstraintViolationExceptions, InvalidKeyHashException, InvalidApplicationKeyException {
    User user = userService.validateAndReturnUserBy(request.headers("AuthKey"));

    ApplicationWrapper applicationWrapper = JsonUtil.deSerialize(request.body(), ApplicationWrapper.class);

    //System.out.println(applicationWrapper.getSecretKey());

    Application application=new Application();
    application.setKey(getApplicationKey(user.getUserName(), applicationWrapper.getType().getName(), applicationWrapper.getName()));
    System.out.println("GEN KEY ::::" + getApplicationKey(user.getUserName(), applicationWrapper.getType().getName(), applicationWrapper.getName()));
    application.setName(applicationWrapper.getName());
    application.setPackageName(applicationWrapper.getPackageName());
    application.setSendOTPInResponse(applicationWrapper.getSendOTPInResponse());
    application.setType(applicationWrapper.getType());

    application.setSignature(applicationWrapper.getSignature());
    application.setCreatedAt(getMysqlTimeStamp());
    application.setCreatedBy(user);
    application.setUpdatedBy(user.getId());
    application.setOtpExpiry(applicationWrapper.getOtpExpiry());
    application.setOtpLength(applicationWrapper.getOtpLength());
    application.setRandomNumber(tempRandomNumber);

    validator.validate(application);
    applicationRepository.create(application);
    System.out.println(applicationWrapper);

    Application thisApp =applicationRepository.getBy(application);
     List<String> secretKeys = applicationWrapper.getSecretKey();
     System.out.println("Application Service ::: \n"+thisApp);
     insertApplicationSecretKeys(secretKeys,thisApp);
    Map<String, String> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
    responseBody.put("application_key", application.getKey());
    responseBody.put("message", "Application created Successfully");

    return new Response("success", responseBody);
}
```

And this is my Mockito + JUnit Test case

```
   @Test
  public void shouldCreate() throws SQLException, ResourceNotFoundException, InvalidSecretKeyException,
          UnsupportedEncodingException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidAuthKeyException, InvalidParametersException, ConstraintViolationExceptions, InvalidKeyHashException, SendGridException, InvalidApplicationKeyException {

    when(request.headers("AuthKey")).thenReturn("some-auth-key");
    when(userService.validateAndReturnUserBy("some-auth-key")).thenReturn(user);
    when(request.body()).thenReturn(JsonUtil.toJson(make(a(ApplicationWrapperMaker.ApplicationWrapper))));
    when(applicationTypeRepository.getByName("WEB")).thenReturn(make(a(ApplicationTypeMaker.ApplicationType)));
    when(userRepository.getByAuthKey("some-auth-key")).thenReturn(user);

    //doNothing().when(appService).insertApplicationSecretKeys(make(a(ApplicationSecretKeyMaker.ApplicationSecretKey)), make(a(Application)));
    //doThrow(new RuntimeException("App created")).when(appService).insertApplicationSecretKeys(make(a(ApplicationSecretKeyMaker.ApplicationSecretKey)), make(a(Application)));

    Response response = applicationService.create(request);

    assertEquals("success", response.getStatus());
    assertNotNull(response.getBody());
  }
```

There is an issue where insertApplicationSecretKeys(secretKeys,thisApp);
Is being called .. As the Created application object is just a mock object this method is returning null and NullPointer exception is coming at this line.

```
this app variable is coming NULL.
```

Please help.

EDIT : HERE IS THE STACKTRACE AND OUTPUT

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sendotp.service.ApplicationService.insertApplicationSecretKeys(ApplicationService.java:297)
    at com.sendotp.service.ApplicationService.create(ApplicationService.java:92)
    at com.sendotp.service.ApplicationServiceTest.shouldCreate(ApplicationServiceTest.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
```

Output ::

```
    GEN KEY ::::AhLDuwI4x34cP6-pr3WJSKoHZ7ltat13CdAcWlkZ8DHyiIk9b8-606JJ9ZPPPbTRWdnU7bPQYp4jphpdfqFoOwHs0uEc0ewE2-MHe8Yyu0XxZZQ7nw7itYVTXNFPp-a2NFP8AZ89QIznIzGstVWyO7eL7DS_qmam8BUF5XHN-VA=
ApplicationWrapper{name='someApplicationName', type=com.sendotp.model.ApplicationType@57f791c6, packageName='some.package.name', otpExpiry=86400, senderId='somesenderId', otpLength=6, requestPerIp=100, key='null', createdBy=null, updatedBy=0, createdAt=null, updatedAt=null, randomNumber='null', secretKey=[121212, 32234324], signature='some-signature,#OTP', sendOTPInResponse=0}
Application Service ::: 
null
```

Comment: You must use spy on the tested object and tell insertApplicationSecretKeys to do nothing

Comment: please check the 2 commented line of codes in the test cases. Am i correct

Comment: but the problem arises when create method gets called

Comment: You are unclear then. You wrote "There is an issue where insertApplicationSecretKeys(secretKeys,thisApp); Is being called". Is the issue happening exactly when you call that method or when you call create? A stacktrace would help. 
By the way, the question is very badly written.

Comment: Apologies for the same .. See when create method is getting called from the test case . THEN 
Application thisApp =applicationRepository.getBy(application);
is returning null and hence insertApplicationSecretKeys is throwing NullPointerException.

Comment: Mock `applicationRepository` and make it return a mock when `getBy` is called.

Comment: Hint: please read about "clean code" and practice to create more human readable code. Looking at your code ... I immediately decided that I am not reputation-hungry enough today to spent my time on digesting such input.

Comment: This code is not written by me man :P thats why i am facing such problem :D by the nice advice for the writer but i have already given hime the same advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `create` is doing too much.

Especially instantiating the `Application` object schould be done outside the method. Object creation of other classes providing business logic should not be doen within the class using this dependency. *Dependency inversion* should be applied.

The simplest way is to pass the `Application` object as parameter to the method (which shold be renamed to `configure` then). In that case you could replace it by a mock on which you could verify the expected method calls.